# How to report bug in french

Tags: bug-reporting, language-support

Sometimes, I see bugs when I use Ubuntu, and I would like to report them, but my english is too bad, so I would like to report them in french.

Is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: From reading your question I think your English is just fine! (I almost gave you an upvote for being funny, but then I remembered this was not facebook :P)

Comment: Well... It's more difficult to make a sentence when I have to report a complex bug :)

Answer (score 2):

You could report and discuss your bug on the [French-speaking forum](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/) first.

Have a look at http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/local-language#french.

Comment: The forum Ubuntu-fr is great when I have some problems to resolve. But this is not the same than https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu